# Is it possible to use different ports for nodes in a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

We are programmatically creating Cassandra nodes (auto-generating yaml and using `CassandraDaemon`).  Ideally we would be able to use different ports on different hosts due to configuration needs.  Is this possible (via seed specification or implementation of a custom class)?  It seems that the seeds list can only take IP addresses and not ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the relevant [source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/net/OutboundTcpConnectionPool.java) in the Cassandra network code, it is apparent that this is not supported.  In the `newSocket()` method, the port for the remote node is obtained from the static `DatabaseDescriptor.getSSLStoragePort()` (excerpt below).  This does not provide a different value per host or any hook to do so:

```
public Socket newSocket() throws IOException
{
    // zero means 'bind on any available port.'
    if (isEncryptedChannel())
    {
        return SSLFactory.getSocket(DatabaseDescriptor.getEncryptionOptions(), endPoint(), DatabaseDescriptor.getSSLStoragePort(), FBUtilities.getLocalAddress(), 0);
    }
    else {
        return new Socket(endPoint(), DatabaseDescriptor.getStoragePort(), FBUtilities.getLocalAddress(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm , they are using multipe cassandra instances on the same node. you can see how they are doing it.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not asking about multiple instances on the same node.  I am asking about instances in the same cluster (but on different hosts) using different ports.

Comment: well as i understand ,this ccm stuff is running different instances on same node on different ports so that instances don't collide on ports and then it puts them in same cluster as well. So its not about having them on same node , its about having different instances running on different ports,,,

Comment: i did take a look but i did not see any evidence of using different ports.  they are using different IPs on the same node, so they don't need to use different ports.

Comment: @MartinSerrano in extension of this idea: you could use a proxy on a server to reroute specific messages to another port. That way you can make it seem like the cassandra server is hosted from one port, while its actually a proxy that does the rerouting.